# Create notepad++ plugin in c#

Tags: c#, notepad++

Is it possible to create notepad++ plug in C#?

I saw some tutorials but all I found is how to write plugins in C++.

Is there any way to do it in c# and where can I find tutorial which explains how to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checkout [NppPlugin.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppPlugin.NET.v0.5.zip/download)

I haven't used it but it claims to include both the project template as well as a sample plug-in.